# Read-only file system

Tags: command-line, permissions

I tried removing an icon of my deleted tor-browser using the command-line in this directory:

```
/snap/kde-frameworks-5-core18/32/usr/share/icons/breeze-dark/apps/48
```

but I received this error:

```
rm: cannot remove 'tor-browser.svg': Read-only file system
```

What should I do?

Comment: Whatever you are doing, *deleting an icon from the theme* is the wrong way to remove an icon from your desktop. That just breaks your theme.

Comment: Snaps are a RO squashfs intentionally, it means you can trust nothing changes, as malicious scripts or programs (even you) cannot change things in the snap. Your approach is wrong, it maybe better if you describe what you want to accomplish.